# What does this 'm' or 'w' shaped symbol mean?

Tags: notation

[image: Bach]

[image: Luther]

Here are two pictures of this m-shaped symbol. One is from a Bach chorale prelude and the other from a hymn melody by Martin Luther.

Comment: It is a *custos*, see line ending part of duplicate question. It indicates the next note in the following line.

Comment: thing is, this question's descriptive title is much more searchable than the older duplicate question. Also, this particular score has the symbol written with such a long tail than some might not recognize it as the same thing in the dup question.

Comment: @MichaelCurtis that's what duplicates are for.  Closing it as a duplicate links the question and both this question and  the other show up and make it easier to find this question in the future.

Comment: Do you mean this one closed as duplicate will show is search results, SE direct and Google?